# Flutter product listing and details using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, state-management

I'm struggling to get definitive answer to this problem I'm having. I have two screens as show below product listing and product details.

[image]

First screen displays list of products **(Firebase documents)** and when you click on an item it takes you to the product details screen. On product display screen you can mark the product as Favorite and has navigation button to previous and next product.

My question is I don't know what I should use **Future** or **Stream** to achieve this.

**Problem using Future** If I use `Future<List<Product>>` I cannot maintain bookmark status of a product unless I refresh the product lists every time I bookmark a product. For example if say I have bookmarked product 2 then navigate to product 3 then back to product 2 the bookmark status is not maintained.

**Problem using Stream** it solves the problem of maintaining bookmarks status but then I don't know how to manage the navigation between products (prev/next)

I have the following code to navigate to next product using **Stream**

```
class SearchResultsBloc implements BlocBase {
  SearchResultsBloc() {
    DatabaseService().Search().listen((data) => _inList.add(data));
  }

  final _listController = BehaviorSubject<List<Product>>();
  Stream<List<Product>> get outList => _listController.stream;
  Sink<List<Product>> get _inList => _listController.sink;

 Stream<Product> outDetails(String uid) {
    return outList.map<Product>((results) => results
        .firstWhere((product) => product.uid == uid, orElse: () => null));
  }

}
```

This method below to retrieves the next product but someone advised that I should not be doing this as the stream could change and also I don't know how I can disable  **< Prev** navigation button if I'm viewing the first product or disable **Next >** if I'm viewing the last product.

```
 Stream<Product> nextProduct(String uid) {
    var index = outList
        .map<int>(
            (results) => results.indexWhere((product) => product.uid == uid))
        .first
        .asStream();

    int nextIndex;
    index.listen((index) {
      nextIndex = index + 1;
    });

    return outList.map<Product>((results) => results.elementAt(nextIndex));
  }
```

Comment: Are you using Streams for a specific reason? If it's data that will not be changing in real time, why don't you just use normal queries?

Comment: Using Streams to update item in real-time. If I use Future and make changes to an item I'll need to refresh the product list.

Comment: Then you just need to listen to the data stream of that specific path on Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) for real-time changes

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream:  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(Your collection).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document.data()[key]),
              subtitle: new Text(document.data()[key]),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

While navigating to the next page, you have to pass snapshot.data so if there are any changes from the backend, it will affect the UI automatically.

Your `outDetails` method seems ok, but you just have to pass snapshot.data.document.data() when the user onTap on a particular `listTile` or your custom widget

Comment: I'm already doing this, I wanted to know how I can manage the prev / next link based on the item currently being viewed.